# How to verify whether partial strings exist in cells across columns in an Excel worksheet?

Tags: excel, string, if-statement, partial, substitution

How can I verify partial strings in cells across columns without having to look for an exact match?

I have a single spreadsheet with two columns that contain corresponding pairs of data in the form of text, or "strings". However, each corresponding pair almost matches except for a couple characters on the end. I need to make excel recognize the pairs despite the inexact string match, and return a "yes" or a "no" as to whether or not there a corresponding pair exists between the two columns. I want it to tell me "yes" or "no" in a single cell.

I do not want to delete characters from either column to make them match, they have to stay as they are.

My solution was that if I used an IF statement to determine whether `A:A=B:B`, all I would need to do is tell excel to also substitute the conflicting text characters with empty spaces, but that didn't work :( It returns #VALUE instead of a yes or no. I placed the function inside `D1`.

This is my formula:

```
=IF(SUBSTITUTE(A:A,"-Z","")*A:A=B:B,"Yes","No")
```

I think maybe I need a formula that will accomplish the following:

If a string with a length of up to 12 characters in a cell of `column A` matches another string in a cell of `column B`, return "true" in `C2`

I don't know what formula that would be. I would appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I understand your are looking at the beginning of string. If suppose 10 or 11 characters match then will it be a match or 12 is minimum number of characters that must match?

Comment: It is a minimum and a maximum of 12 characters, because many strings begin with some of the same characters. All the strings have more than 12 characters. I had attempted to use the substitute function to make the IF statement ignore everything after the 12th character in the A column when comparing columns A & B. So yes, I am looking at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(--(LEFT($A$2:$A$23,12)=LEFT(B2,12)))>0,"TRUE","FALSE")`. It will first extract first 12 characters from strings in `column A`, then compare it to the first 12 characters in `column B`. Adjust range to your needs.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for considering my question. I'll have to try that. The next thing I'll have to do is use a function that will do the same thing, but return a "yes" or a "no" in one cell. The purpose of the form is to help people determine if we have a certain component on hand to process a piece of equipment. If we have the digital program loaded onto the machine, but not the physical component (identified by the same name except for a few characters), then we can't operate with that program and can move on to the next task.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLOOKUP construct like below in cell C2 and then copy down:

`=IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,12)&"*",B:B,1,0)),"NO","YES")`